# Копирование файла/папки С++

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть ли какая то функция, которая копирует файл или папку со всеми её подпапками?
Или через что это можно провернуть без использования огромных макросов и прочего?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy  3-м аргументом установить опцию recursive.